# URL pattern matching in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I'm trying to implement java like url pattern matching in php. Suppose i have a link which leads to a file called find.php (Example is shown below)

http://www.xyz.com/MyWebsite/TryToFind/find.php?search=abc+def

Then i want to expose the follwing link to the users, say,

http://www.xyz.com/Search?search=abc+def

then i want to match this(2nd url pattern) url to the one i have provided above(1st url pattern) using a controller. This is because i want to hide the exact uri pattern to the user and also the hide the extension which i have used.

Please Help Me Guys...

Regards,
Abilash

Comment: Mod_Rewrite? [http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using apache (which I assume you are as you have tagged `.htaccess`) as your http server then you can use Apache's Mod_Rewrite Module. It usually ships with most installations of Apache these days and anyways you can install one yourself if it is not present.

Mod_Rewrite will enable you to achieve what you desire, In fact it is designed for that purpose only. While php frameworks like CodeIgniter provide some programming support for Mod_Rewrite, working directly with `.htaccess` using the Regex will render you with more power and flexibility.

A full explaination is difficult here. But [this was the tutorial](http://workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) I found handy when learning the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. But if i say * and redirect all controls to a controller and then if i use a header() function i'll still be revealing the file name. I want to hide the file name completely. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: But how will your controller differentiate one `*` from another `*`? Also note that by having clean url like http://example.com/search/keyword you are making your website not only 'Google' friendly but also make things more intuitive for the user, adding to the UX.

Comment: And Mod_Rewrite is simple if you can overcome the initial obstacles. There are quite a few, possibly, even simpler tutorials over the net.

Comment: I'm planning to redirect every request to a controller (Front Controller) and then take a decision based on the request. So i'll use pregmatch() for uri matching and then a header() to redirect, still i'll be revealing the name of the file.

Comment: So i think i can overcome this by having match for each url pattern in my .htaccess file. But it makes my .htaccess file large. Will this affect performance?

Comment: 1) Yes you are right `header()` will reveal your URL(s).  2) At more advanced levels you can create 'modular' regex in `.htaccess` implying that a single expression can handle a full family of URLs there by reducing the size of your `.htaccess`, Furthermore, performance should not be such a great issue anyways.

Comment: ok... Thank you very much sir.... Have a nice day, If You Are An Indian, else good night :-)